# What is wrong with the following SQL left join?

Tags: sql, join

I have 5 tables: A, B, C, D, E

A: {ID, Value, GroupID, FilterID, In_Date}

B: {ID, Description, Out_Date, From_Date }

C: {ID, Category}

D: {GroupID, GroupName}

E: {FilterID, FilterName}

There could be missing IDs in B and C as a result, I'm trying to do a LEFT JOIN to get the required info. In my dataset, I've explicitly added a row in A with ID that's not in B or C. I expect it to be picked up in the following query, but it doesn't happen. I believe I'm going wrong in the WHERE clause due to null values in B and C.

```
SELECT A.Value, A.Group, B.Description, C.Category, D.GroupName, E.FilterName 
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID     
       LEFT JOIN C ON A.ID = C.ID,
     D,E
WHERE
B.Out_Date>A.In_Date,
A.GroupID=D.GroupID,
A.FilterID=E.FilterID
```

How can I fix this to retrieve the fields I want with null values when the ID is not in B or C , but in A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Don't mix old comma separated join syntax with modern explicit join syntax!

2) When `left join`, put the right side table's conditions in the `ON` clause to get true left join behavior. (When in `WHERE` you get inner join result.)

```
SELECT A.Value, A.Group, B.Description, C.Category, D.GroupName, E.FilterName 
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.Out_Date > A.In_Date
       LEFT JOIN C ON A.ID = C.ID
       JOIN D ON A.GroupID = D.GroupID
       JOIN E ON A.FilterID = E.FilterID
```

`Value` and `Group` are reserved words in ANSI SQL, so you may need to delimit them, as `"Value"` and `"Group"`.

Comment: Looks like we had the same idea

Comment: @HoneyBadger, well, can it be anything else?

Answer (score 1):

First point: You shouldn't mix `join` syntaxes, just use explicit syntax.

Because of your `where` clause, you effectively turn your `left joins` in `inner joins`. You are probably looking for:

```
SELECT     A.Value, A.Group, B.Description, C.Category, D.GroupName, E.FilterName 
FROM       A 
LEFT JOIN  B 
       ON  A.ID = B.ID 
       AND B.Out_Date > A.In_Date
LEFT JOIN  C 
        ON A.ID = C.ID
INNER JOIN D
        ON A.GroupID = D.GroupID
INNER JOIN E
        ON A.FilterID = E.FilterID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query for your problem.

```
SELECT     A.Value, A.Group, B.Description, C.Category, D.GroupName, E.FilterName 
FROM       A 
LEFT JOIN  B 
   ON  A.ID = B.ID 
   AND B.Out_Date > A.In_Date
LEFT JOIN  C 
    ON A.ID = C.ID
LEFT JOIN D
    ON A.GroupID = D.GroupID
LEFT JOIN E
    ON A.FilterID = E.FilterID
```

Comment: Yes but you have used inner join and I have used left join.

Comment: Ah yes, missed that. I'll remove my comment. It would help, never-the-less, if you added some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your table details

A: {ID, Value, GroupID, FilterID, In_Date}

B: {ID, Description, Out_Date, From_Date }

C: {ID, Category}

D: {GroupID, GroupName}

E: {FilterID, FilterName}

now you try to retrieve data using left join
so you try the flowing script

```
      SELECT A.Value, A.Group, B.Description, C.Category, D.GroupName,E.FilterName from A left join B on A.ID=B.ID
left Join C on A.ID=C.ID
Left Join D on A.GroupID=D.GroupID
Left Join E on A.FilterID=E.FilterID
where B.Out_Date>A.In_Date
```

I hope this is help full for you.

Comment: B table is not left joined here, since you have B.Out_Date in the where clause.